# Incorrect redirection for a single post category

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-urls, django-2.1

I'm developing my personal blog; it has only two categories and I would like to have a specific list of posts for both categories.

For this reason I've expand *get_absolute_url* as you can see below:

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
    ('G.I.S.', 'G.I.S.'),
    ('Sustainable Mobility', 'Sustainable Mobility'),
)

class Blog(models.Model):
    """
    Blog's post definition
    """
    title = models.CharField(
                max_length=70,
                unique=True,
                )
    slug = models.SlugField(
            unique=True,
            )
    contents = models.TextField()
    publishing_date = models.DateTimeField()
    category = models.CharField(
                    max_length=50,
                    choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES,
                    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        if Blog.objects.filter(category="G.I.S."):
            return reverse("gis_single_post", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
        if Blog.objects.filter(category="Sustainable Mobility"):
            return reverse("sumo_single_post", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
```

Below you can see **views.py**; it has different model based on a category:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView

from .models import Blog


class GisSinglePost(DetailView):
    model = Blog
    queryset = Blog.objects.filter(category="G.I.S.")
    context_object_name = 'post'
    template_name = "gis_single_post.html"


class GisListPost(ListView):
    model = Blog
    queryset = Blog.objects.filter(category="G.I.S.")
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    template_name = "gis_list_post.html"


class SuMoSinglePost(DetailView):
    model = Blog
    queryset = Blog.objects.filter(category="Sustainable Mobility")
    context_object_name = 'post'
    template_name = "sumo_single_post.html"


class SuMoListPost(ListView):
    model = Blog
    queryset = Blog.objects.filter(category="Sustainable Mobility")
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    template_name = "sumo_list_post.html"
```

And below there is **urls.py** with its four path:

```
from django.urls import include, path
from .views import GisSinglePost, GisListPost, SuMoListPost, SuMoSinglePost

urlpatterns = [
        path("gis/", GisListPost.as_view(), name="gis_list_post"),
        path("gis/<slug:slug>/", GisSinglePost.as_view(), name="gis_single_post"),
        path("sustainable-mobility/", SuMoListPost.as_view(), name="sumo_list_post"),
        path("sustainable-mobility/<slug:slug>/", SuMoSinglePost.as_view(), name="sumo_single_post"),
]
```

When I click on a single post of GIS's category it's shown the relative details without problem. But when I click on a post of the other category it's shown to me this:

> Page not found (404) Request Method:  GET Request URL:
>     http://127.0.0.1:8000/gis/erova-mobilita/ Raised by:
>     blog.views.GisSinglePost
>
> No Articolo found matching the query
>
> You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django
>   settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a
>   standard 404 page.

I've been stuck on this problem for many days. **How I can resolve**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should redefine your `get_absolute_url` method. Since your Blog instances with category G.I.S exist you are never reaching second if for Blog instances with category Sustainable Mobility.

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    if self.category == "G.I.S.":
        return reverse("gis_single_post", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
    elif self.category == "Sustainable Mobility":
       return reverse("sumo_single_post", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
```

Comment: How I can redefine it?

Comment: Please see edited answer. Ok, I see that someone jumped in directly with the answer. Of course without the explanation why. Interesting approach.

Answer (score 1):

Try to redefine your get_absolute_url(self) in the next way:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    if self.category == "G.I.S.":
        return reverse("gis_single_post", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
    if self.category == "Sustainable Mobility":
        return reverse("sumo_single_post", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
```